# datetime, icu - не совпадает время

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в `d1` время на 1 час назад, а в `d2` нет?

```
from icu import Locale, SimpleDateFormat
from datetime import datetime

d1 = SimpleDateFormat('dd/MMM/yy HH:mm', Locale('ru')).parse('04/июн/12 11:56')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(d1))  # 2012-06-04 10:56:00

d2 = SimpleDateFormat('dd/MMM/yy HH:mm', Locale('ru')).parse('15/февр/19 20:42')
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(d2))  # 2019-02-15 20:42:00
```

Comment: Очевидно, какая-то муть с часовыми поясами, потому что сейчас в Москве UTC+3, а в 2012 году было UTC+4 (но как конкретно это относится к данному коду, не знаю, с icu никогда не работал)

Comment: да, спасибо, все верно

Answer (score 1):

```
from icu import Locale, SimpleDateFormat, ICUtzinfo
from datetime import datetime

d1 = SimpleDateFormat('dd/MMM/yy HH:mm', Locale('ru')).parse('04/июн/12 11:56')
datetime.fromtimestamp(d1, ICUtzinfo.getDefault()).replace(tzinfo=None)  # 2012-06-04 11:56:00
```